# C# easy way to convert a split string into columns

Tags: c#

This is a rough one to explain.  What I have is a string,

```
string startString = "Operations\t325\t65\t0\t10\t400"
string[] splitStart = startString.Split('\t');
```

I need to turn this into

```
Operations|325
Operations|65
Operations|0
Operations|10
Operations|400
```

The problem is i need this so be dynamic to if it has 10 splits I need it to do the same process 10 times, if it has 4, then it needs to do 4.

Any help would be awesome.

Sorry for any confusion, Operations is just this string, so it's not static.  It really need to be [0] of the string split.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like:

```
string startString = "Operations\t325\t65\t0\t10\t400"
string[] splitStart = startString.Split('\t');

List<string> result = new List<string>();

if(splitStart.Length > 1)
   for(int i = 1; i < splitStart.Length; i++)
   {
      result.Add(splitStart[0] + "|" + splitStart[i]);
   }
```

Comment: Thanks Tudor, how do I not exceed the the 4 int if i have like 7 of them...?

Comment: @Mike: you want to only take the first 4 ints?

Answer (score 0):

If it is the strings you want, a little Linq should be fine:

```
string startString = "Operations\t325\t65\t0\t10\t400";
var operations = startString.Split('\t').Select(str => "Operations|" + str);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
    var reFormatted = new List<string>();
    foreach (var roughOne in toExplain) 
    {
        // example of roughOne "Operations\t325\t65\t0\t10\t400"
        var segments = roughOne.Split("\t");
        var firstSegment = segments.First();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var otherSegment in segments.Skip(1))
        {
            sb.Append(firstSegment);
            sb.Append("|")
            sb.Append(otherSegment);
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        reFormatted.Add(sb.ToString());
    }
```